# SSIS Oracle Data Load is Incomplete

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, ssis

I have a data flow task where the data from oracle source is fetched and stored in SQL Server DB after nearly 400k rows the data flow fails with following error.

ORA-01489 result of string concatenation is too long

[image]

[image]

I the Execution results the [Oracle Source [1543]] Error: what this exactly means.

Comment: "result of string concatenation is too long" - that seems self-explanatory.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long battle i decided to modify the package and it turns that deleting and creating the all the tasks again has solved the problem.

Real cause is still unknown to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using `varchar2` datatype which limits to 4000 chars.

This error is because the concatenated string returns more than 4000 chars of varchar2 which exceeds the limit try using [CLOB datatype.](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html)

http://nimishgarg.blogspot.in/2012/06/ora-01489-result-of-string.html

Comment: I really don't have any idea of ORCALE queries, but seems if i am using SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1="humans" and suppose my COL2 is of VARCHAR2 type how will be my select query then

Comment: @PratikGupta Can you post the entire query which includes concat operations.

Comment: IT's just a [SELECT * FROM view_item_details] its a view only.

Comment: @Pratik Then your view definition must have contained a string concatenation that results in a string greater than the char limit of the field.  I think you should consider accepting this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

use a derived column after your source to cut the strings to 4000 chars

Comment: Diego i have kept the length of the destination as MAX but the oracle data which is coming is not fixed i think and that is causing problem.Can you explain how a derived column will help :

Comment: it would help because it seems to me that the error is occurring before the destination is reach. where is the error actually occurring?

Comment: Diego i have updated my question and posted where exactly the error occured.Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your data source (Oracle) is sending out strings that are larger than 4000 characters while your SSIS source expects something less than that. Check your source for any data that has a length > 4000.